# Sum Product two table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, sumproduct

I have two table like these:
Table1 with Col1, Col2
and Tbale2 with Col3, col4

I want to do 2 task:
1- creating a new column in Table1 that lookup Col4
2- a column that include Table1.Col2 * Table2.Col4 as Col5
3- a measure calculate Sum (Table1.Col2 * Table2.Col4)

how can I do it??

Comment: Question is lacking details/clarity. (1) How are the two tables related for the Lookup? Add some sample tables for both in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/). Help visualize your question.

Comment: Table = T
Column = C

two tables are related with t1.c1 and t2.c3.

Comment: Is there are a relationship between to the two tables on those columns? You're not helping us to help you.